# Is there a simpler way to create a borderless window with XNA 4.0?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0

When looking into making my XNA game's window border-less, I found no properties or methods under `Game.Window` that would provide this, but I did find a window handle to the form.

I was able to accomplish what I wanted by doing this:

```
IntPtr hWnd = this.Window.Handle;
var control = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle( hWnd );
var form = control.FindForm();
form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

I don't know why but this feels like a dirty hack.  Is there a built-in way to do this in XNA that I'm missing?

Comment: No there isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a "simpler" way.

You're right in thinking that it is "hacky". It depends on internal implementation details of XNA. Which means it could break in future versions of XNA (there's nothing saying that XNA's `Game` class needs to use a `Form`). Also - in *theory* it might fail in unexpected ways - the XNA team hasn't necessarily tested this behaviour at all - let alone extensively.

(Note that XNA games are version-specific. For example: An XNA 3 game requires XNA 3 and won't run on XNA 4. So your binary is pretty safe against framework updates - but not necessaraly your code.)

There *is* a non-hacky way, by creating your own alternative to the `Game` class. The [WinForms sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1) shows you how. But then you lose all the helpful stuff that `Game` and its friends provides (most notably the timing stuff).

**But** - because this is such a trivial settings change, it's probably completely safe to do in this case. And worth the risk, given the alternative is much trickier to implement. Maybe you could add some error-checking/exception handling - but even that's probably not necessary for this specific case.

I'm pretty sure XNA won't care if the `FormBorderStyle` changes out from under it.

(Of course, I've seen people pulling out the `Form` and doing some extremely *brazen* things with it. If you need to do anything beyond tweaking a few settings - I recommend going the "WinForms Sample" route.)

Comment: "there's nothing saying that XNA's Game class needs to use a Form" Well he is saying it (at least that his game needs a form), when he says that he needs border-less window...

Comment: `it might fail in unexpected ways` - This has been my primary concern. The only reason I'm doing this is to provide a feature to display the game in a borderless-maximized (sort of faux-fullscreen) mode for the gamer. I suppose if this ends up causing any issues down the road, I could always just yank the feature and blame XNA. :P

Comment: I have a few editors that use the Windows Forms route (so I'm familiar with the technique), but to be honest, it would have been a lot more work than the feature it would implement is even worth. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Not that's it's any different, but you can also do this.

```
using System.Windows.Form;

Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Form gameForm = (Form)Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
gameForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

I think it's worth posting this here as i've never run into any problems at all with this code.

Comment: Not that there's anything wrong with this method, but I built a `Control` from the `IntPtr` because I didn't want to assume that it would always be a pointer to a `Form` since I don't really know what the underlying XNA code is actually doing.  And since just about *everything* GUI-related in .NET is inherited from `Control`, I figured I was pretty safe.